# How do I fix a broken stylus pen?

Tags: technology

My baby brother chewed on the tip of my stylus pen, resulting in my iPad not responding to the touch of the pen anymore. It has chew marks on the sides, so I’m not sure how to fix that. I’m hoping it’s not permanently damaged. Is there anyway to make the pen work?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually an extra tip in the packaging of the stylus, you can check this out and replace the tip.